# git svn clone failed with couldn't truncate file at

Tags: windows, git, svn

Tried to clone my SVN repository with:

```
git svn clone URL -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

and got this weird error:

```
couldn't truncate file at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git.pm line 1322.
```

How can I solve this?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried it again with gitbash instead of windows terminal -> all OK!

Comment: it did not worked for me. `git version= 2.31.1.windows.1`